# What is the recommended way to cite papers in LNCS volumes in Bib(La)TeX?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, citing

What is the correct way to cite papers that appear in volumes of "Lecture Notes in Computer Science"?  These papers appeared at various conferences.

- Using `@inproceedings` separates "LNCS" from the volume number, which is quite confusing in my opinion.
- Using `@incollection` produces better output, but seems misleading because these are papers from a conference, rather than some other kind of collection.

In case it is relevant, I am using the ACM BibLaTeX format.

Comment: I can't comment on the ACM rules specifically, but I almost never use the `@inproceedings` type but always use `@incollection` for conference proceedings papers. I wouldn't take the entry types so literally. Conference proceedings are volumes of collected papers from that conference, so the `@incollection` type is appropriate most of the time.

Comment: @AlanMunn Out of curiousity, when would `@inproceedings` be appropriate, in your opinion?  (I acknowledge that you rarely use it.)

Comment: A quick grep of my ~3600 entry `.bib` file finds 28 `@inproceedings` entries. Their most salient property seems to be that they were added very early when I didn't know any better. :) Their second salient property seems to be that they're papers where I had very minimal information about the paper, usually just author, year, title and conference.   But all of the papers which have full information (editors, pages etc.) are `@incollection`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the standard styles/data model the difference between `@inproceedings` and `@incollection` isn't actually all that big.

- `@inproceedings` has extra fields for `venue`, `eventdate` and `eventtitle` to specify more conference information (if the data given in the `booktitle` or `booktitleaddon` is not sufficient). It also supports an `organization` field for the organising ... organisation.
- `@inproceedings` does not have an `edition` field. (Presumably because it is expected that there is never going to be a new edition of conference proceedings. Once they're published that's it.)

Semantically the only difference is that you know that an `@inproceedings` comes from a collection of conference papers, whereas an `@incollection` might be any old collection of papers. I think it doesn't hurt to make the distinction if it is easily made, but wouldn't worry about it too much if it's not easily done.

If the style you use behaves differently and gives undesirable output for both cases, check its documentation for guidance. If there is none, it might be a good idea to contact the developer about it.

---

Note that "Lecture Notes in Computer Science" is a `series` in `biblatex` parlance and the number of a book in that series belongs in the `number` field even if Springer talks about volumes.

---

Grabbing an example from the current start page of LNCS I could imagine using the following entry

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{clouet,
  author         = {Clouet, Myriam and Antignac, Thibaud
                    and Arnaud, Mathilde and Signoles, Julien},
  editor         = {Prevosto, Virgile and Seceleanu, Cristina},
  title          = {Context Specification Language for
                    Formally Verifying Consent Properties
                    on Models and Code},
  booktitle      = {Tests and Proofs},
  booktitleaddon = {Proceedings of the 17th International Conference on Tests and Proofs},
  year           = {2023},
  publisher      = {Springer Nature Switzerland},
  address        = {Cham},
  pages          = {68--93},
  eventtitle     = {TAP 2023},
  venue          = {Leicester, UK},
  eventdate      = {2023-07-18/2023-07-19},
  series         = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
  number         = {14066},
  doi            = {10.1007/978-3-031-38828-6_50},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,clouet}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Clouet, Myriam et al. (2023). ‘Context Specification Language for Formally Veri- fying Consent Properties on Models and Code’. In: Tests and Proofs. Pro- ceedings of the 17th International Conference on Tests and Proofs. TAP 2023 (Leicester, UK, 18th–19th July 2023). Ed. by Virgile Prevosto and Cristina Seceleanu. Lecture Notes in Computer Science 14066. Cham: Springer Nature Switzerland, pp. 68–93. doi: 10.1007/978-3-031-38828-6_50.]

YMMV especially with respect to the `booktitle` and `booktitleaddon` field: You may just want to have

```
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 17th International Conference on Tests and Proofs},
```

and no `booktitleaddon` because the "Tests and Proofs" is part of the conference name.

You may or may not be interested in all the `eventtitle`, `venue`, `eventdate` stuff and may want to drop it.